# How do I compare all files in dir to another file and print output of common lines

Tags: grep, diff, file-comparison

First I have a dir/ consisting of 100 .txt files

`john_1.txt`, `john_2.txt`, `john_3.txt`, `john_4.txt` etc, that consists of ex. `id;email;name;phone`
and then I have one other file `emails.txt` that consists of e-mail adresses listed line by line.

How do I compare all the files to this emails file and print the common lines.

`grep` or `diff`?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, something like this:

```
awk -F\; 'NR == FNR {A[$0]=1; next}; A[$2] == 1;' emails.txt john*.txt
```

`NR == FNR` tests if the record (line) number counted over all files is the the same as the record number in current file, which is a funny way of testing if this is the first file. If it is, we take the full line read (`$0`) and use it as a key to an associative array called `A`, setting the value to one, and jumping to the `next` line of input. If it wasn't the first file (the jump wasn't taken), take the second field (`$2`) on the line, separated by semicolons (set by `-F`) and see if the corresponding value in the array `A` is one. If it is, the default action is to print the whole line. You could add, say, `{print $1}` to only print the first field.

---

With `grep` you could just do

```
grep -F -f emails.txt john*.txt
```

(`-F` for fixed string patterns, `-f` to read patterns from a file.)
But this will print partial matches too, and also matches from other fields in the file, but that might not be a problem with names, phone numbers and email addresses.

Though that could be worked around by adding semicolons to the start and end of each line used as a pattern. This should work if process substitution is supported:

```
grep -F -f <(sed -e 's/^/;/' -e 's/$/;/' emails.txt) john*.txt
```

Comment: I misstyped, the files are not named 1.txt , 2.txt, 3.txt.  it's like john_1.txt , john_2.txt , john_125.txt. how do i command that, or just the whole dir (cuz all files are in that dir)

Comment: something like `john*.txt` or `dir/*.txt`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob . Though if everything is in the same directory, `*.txt` would include the `emails` file too, and print everything there.